# Why does this bash script generate Exit code 2 in i3block?

Tags: bash, scripts, i3-wm

I used this bash script for i3block, but I get Exit code 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
sink=$(pacmd list-sinks | grep '* index:')
if [[ "${sink:11:11}" -eq "1" ]]
then
    echo 'usb'
else
    echo 'mic'
fi
```

The script works fine when run from the command line, but it doesn't work for i3block, why?

Comment: How are you using this script in i3block? Does it work if you change the `if` to `if [ "${sink:11:11}" -eq "1" ]` (using single instead of double braces)? It might be that i3block is executing this as an sh script and not bash and `[[` is a bash thing.